# JSP Parse Date failing: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date

Tags: java, jsp

I have a string `2008-09-18 00:00:00.0` in my model, and I want to display it on my JSP page in the format: `Sep 18 2008`

I try this:

```
<fmt:parseDate value="${myObj.myDate}" type="date" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.s" var="formatedDate"/>   
<fmt:formatDate value="${formatedDate}"  type="date" pattern="MMM dd yyyy"/>
```

But I repeatedly get the error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2008-09-18 00:00:00.0"
```

I've tried the pattern in a bunch of different combinations:

- yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.s
- yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S
- yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss
- yyyy-MM-dd
- yyyy-mm-dd

Same result each time.

but I don't understand what about the pattern is not parsable, and the error message is not too descriptive.

Any ideas?

Comment: If nothing else, the millisecond should be an `S`, not `s`, which is seconds.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks! I tried that too, and I got the same error back

Answer (score 1):

Make the following two changes in your `parseDate` tag.

1. Change the `type` from 'date' to 'both'. Your input date contains both date and time.
2. Optionally specify an additional attribute `timeStyle` with a value of either 'full' or 'long' or 'medium'.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try "to split" the **date** you are trying to parse?

I was trying to do something similar, but to convert **LocalDate and LocalDateTime** to ***jsp view***.

```html
<fmt:parseDate value="${date.year}-${date.monthValue}-${date.dayOfMonth} ${date.hour}:${date.minute}:${date.second}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" var="parsedDate" type="both" timeStyle="long"/>
```

It was particulary usefull to me, because type LocalDate was displaying the *dayOfMonth* even the previous day (ex: if real day was 05, it displayed 04).

```html
<fmt:parseDate value="${date.year}-${date.monthValue}-${date.dayOfMonth + 1}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" var="parsedDate" type="date"/>
```